# enforce a method to be called java

Tags: java

I have a set of classes `A1` to `An`  of such form :

```
public class A1{

    //constructor method
    public A1(...){...}
    //init method
    public void init(){...}
    //some class specific method
    ...
}
```

I would like to ensure that method `init` is always called after the class initialization (possibly a compiler error or some sort of warning if not used) .

Something like:

```
A1 a1=new A1(...);
//some other code that may relate to a1 (e.g. changing default global values)
a1.init(); // <-- if not used some bad things happens.
```

The only limitation is:

**that I cannot use the `init()` method within constructor**

So is there any way of doing it? (except calling the `init()` in constructor of course).

Comment: It isn't a good idea in general to enforce a specific order of method calls in objects (though sometimes it's unavoidable). The preferred way is to use builders or composition in these cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a boolean in class to false, set it to true in init() and avoid to call any method if not true.

```
public class A1{

    boolean initialized = false;

    //constructor method
    public A1(...){...}

    //init method
    public void init()
    {
        // do init stuff
        initialized = true;
    }

    //some class specific method
    public void myMethod() { 
        if(!initialized) {
            // print error
        } else {
            // do your stuff
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: that's clever . never thought of it

Comment: if you forget to add a validation **in any part of your code** bad things will happen always... not only here ;)

Comment: @JordiCastilla That is true, but this is a particularly brittle solution. Particularly in a multi-threaded environment.

Comment: @biziclop agree... I just answered for this *single case*, didn't try to create a new pattern... just gave a sollution to OP....

Comment: @JordiCastilla this solution meets my requirement the most eventhough its a dirty hack.  but this way I can keep all my classes identical

Answer (score 4):

You can restructure your class like this:

```
public class A1{

   //constructor method
   private A1(...){...}
   //init method
   private void init(){...}
   //some class specific method
   ...
   public static A1 create(...) {
       A1 ret = new A1(...);
       ret.init();
       return ret;
   }
}
```

Using static factory methods instead of constructors can be preferable for other reasons too, you can give them more expressive names and you can overload them in ways you can't overload a constructor.

*P.s.: You can read more about this in Josh Bloch's Effective Java, it's Item 1, but the other object creation tips may be appropriate for your case too.*

Comment: hmm, it would work if I was going to use the API, unfortunately depending on the use a set of default values may change ( some codes between class constructor and the init method)

Comment: That code can be injected as a strategy. But the way you describe it, it sounds like there are some issues with the design. Why should there be code between the creation of `A1` and the call to the `init()` method that doesn't use the newly created object but has an effect on `init()`?

Comment: you solution is certainly clever,  but since there are many classes and I tried to keep the design very easy to use so others can simply use them with minimal difference between how to define the classes. of course the draw back was that if someone wants to change the default values they have to do it before calling the `init` method.

Comment: I don't see that as a drawback. You should try to avoid depending on global values and default values as much as possible. Ideally an object's state should only depend on values explicitly passed to it either in the constructor or through some method. Anything else makes the design brittle, hard to test, hard to reason about in a multi-threaded environment, and prone to spooky actions at a distance.

Answer (score 2):

You could extract the `init()` method's body to a initializer block. Something like:

```
public class A1 {
    {
        //here goes the body of the init() method
        //this will always be executed before the constructor
    }

    //constructor
    public A1() { }
}
```

It will be executed before each class instance is created (i.e. before the constructor).

When you instantiate the class with `A1 instance = new A1()`, then the initializer block will **always** be executed first and then the constructor body will be executed. And this goes for every instance of the class you create.

Comment: hmm intersting concept, if i do this when exactly this piece of code gets executed? e.g. right after method initialization or after I changed some default values?

Comment: It gets executed *before* the body of the constructor is executed.